# disable auto scrolling in Visual Studio SSIS package design mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

Right now when I am in a Visual Studio SSIS package in design view, if I select an element it auto-scrolls to that item. Is there anyway to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross posted this on the MSDN forums and learned there is no way to change this setting.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e71931d0-ef00-4129-9cf2-8ef5d1142f08/disable-auto-scrolling-in-visual-studio-ssis-package-design-mode?forum=sqlintegrationservices